# Converting svg to grid map

Tags: java, android, a-star

I have a svg file which contains a map.

Ive written an a* algorithm, which I want to use to path find within this svg map.

I was wondering if anyone knows a good way to convert the svg map to a grid map 
ie

0 0 0 0

1 0 1 0

0 1 1 0

1 0 1 1
...

(0 = open, 1 = wall)

for use with a* algorithm.

This will be done in Java on Android platform.